# Possible to host a rails app and a PHP app on nginx server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, deployment, nginx

I currenly running a rails web app on nginx on ubuntu, now I aim to deploy a wordpress instance to it also. Is it possible to deploy a wordpress instance also to nginx server. I try to search on internet but it gives different ways to integrate php and nginx server to run WordPress. I've confused much more with these different posts on internet. Do you suggest a way to accomplished it in a easy way?

By the way I am currently running a rails application on that nginx server that comes from "Passenger" installation.

Comment: Did you try here : http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress

Comment: This is so much overview. In Addition I am currently running a Rails app on that server so I need a certain solution :(

Comment: @JustinT.: A [similar tutorial (HOWTO: Install WordPress on Nginx)](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/) lead the OP to the following error: [Nginx PHP5 combination gives 403 error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11120090/367456) - You might know more about that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking for a tutorial that targeted not only at Nginx and Wordpress, but also for other details of your situation: What operating system you are installing on, and whether you are looking for a single site or multi-site installation.

For example, here's a [nice step-by-step tutorial for installing Wordpress on Nginx](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/), but in your case, perhaps 'spawn-fcgi' can be installed from a package instead, or perhaps you need multi-site support.

It should not be a conflict that you already have a Rails app running on the same server.

Comment: Exactly the tutorial you linked lead the OP to the following error: [Nginx PHP5 combination gives 403 error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11120090/367456) - You might know more about that as well.