# Nginx PHP5 combination gives 403 error

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I try to embed a wordpress instance to nginx server that also works with my already installed Rails application. I used all the same with [that writing (HOWTO: Install WordPress on Nginx; no Date given)](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/) but it gives 403 error for all requests.

How could I understand the reason of that permission error. Logs does not include further information. Is it about the permission problem on fast-cgi or any running process?

This is also my current setting:

```
 server{
       listen 80;
       server_name www.bla.com bla.com;
       root /opt/nginx/wordpress/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
       location ~ \.php$ {
          include     fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass localhost:53217;

          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       }
   }
```

Comment: what a clever answer... thanks... I know your sayings... But I have my server on my own so I need to solve it alone. ALso it is a programic problem that need to be solved

Comment: Well, the vendor offers self-support options as well. It's an open source project, so go ahead I'm not stopping you. That's what we expect first. Also there is a server related FAQ site as well, I have just suggested to move your question. Other programmers will still see it here and might decide differently, I only did the comment in good faith not that you post the question here with wrong expectations. Also you should locate where the error relates from. Normally 403's are logged by nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 is the HTTP status code for "Forbidden".

I recommend debugging it by continuing to simplify your server configuration until you quit getting the error. The problem is then in whatever you removed last. :).

For example, you could temporarily comment your rails app and see if you still get the problem, and then try commenting out all our some of your wordpress server{} definition and see if you still have the problem.

I also recommend searching through your nginx configuration for the words 'allow' and 'deny' as they are used to control access. If access is "denied" to a location, it could result in a 403.